# mediaPlayer prepare nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player, prepare

it's realy rare error for me but.. It's error. Can't understand why. 
error just on line

```
mp.prepare();
```

from logcat :

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at myapp.activity.com.myApp.media(myApp.java:281)
            at myapp.activity.com.myApp$showLogotype.doInBackground(myApp.java:397)
            at myapp.activity.com.myApp$showLogotype.doInBackground(myApp.java:1)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305
```

Someone can explain me :( ?

Im using  asynctask for prepare and load all datas and showing logo while my app reading datas and preparing for mediaPlayer( in logcat : mediaPlayer.prepare() getting 5-10 seconds) )
But im sometimes have this realy rare error for me(cos i can't understand how to get this error and he is realy rare for me)

Please explain me if anyone know :( or please< tell me how to fix this  :(
code of function :

```
 public void media() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException
    {

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(stream);
        mp.prepare();

    }
```

Regards,Peter. Sorry for my bad english, hope u understand me

Comment: Did you first do `MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();` and `mp.setDataSource(...);`? If not, then make sure you have completed that first.

Comment: yes, i have it. I updated my post. And i call this function when app started.

Comment: Have you also verified that `stream` is not null?

Comment: yes, stream != null . Is i sayd already, this error very rare for me. 100-300 times to run app and maybe than i can get error .

Comment: Okay. There may be a chance it has nothing to do with your app code, and it is a device related problem. You could put it in a try/catch block, and maybe in the first catch block, try/catch again, and then if it still doesn't work, show the user an error. I don't think there's really any true solution to your issue, though, because if it is that inconsistent, then it is very likely **not** a coding error.

Comment: @Jakar okay dude, media preparing in asyntask.. and i show splash screen while media preparing.. (spesialy i set mp = null before mp.prepare and it's show me error at start my app. I get mp.prepare to try/catch and my app running normaly BUT than.. i click on playbutton and app crashed.. cos mp = null :( i can't understand why   i have error in this line( it's if im not setting mp=null ) My friend who tested this app sayd me : App crashed at start .. that's all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't catch this problem. I manualy catch and solve for some problem. I think media player have a bug .. .and this problem not fixing.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception happens when you try to access a variable or object that is not properly assigned/instantiated. My guess is that you either have not assigned the media player, or have not given the player the data you want to prepare. Resource: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: what is stream coming from? And I assume mp is not only defined in onCreate and that it is accessible to media().

Comment: stream coming from url . http://199.16.186.34:8244/  it's free radio .. founded when google show me on request : SHOUTcast D.N.A.S. Status